# Does the Demo data transfer to both the eShop and Cartridge Full Versions?

Tags: bravely-default-demo

The eShop's demo for Bravely Default says that **some** demo data and bonuses will transfer to the full version of the game.  But do I have to worry about buying the eShop versus the Cartridge version of Bravely Default, or will the demo data transfer to both versions of the full game?

Comment: I can't imagine them being different. That would take some incredible lack of foresight.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda agree, but I'm not sure where I got that idea. Hopefully someone from a region where it's been released can confirm the actual behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Card and e-Shop editions are identical from everything I have seen & heard. So all of your bonuses should transfer identically on both.

I haven't heard of a single instance of a game that is different between the retail and downloadable versions on the 3DS.

Comment: The only real difference between eShop and card-based games is that the eShop version is licensed to your account and you can only have one 3DS linked to an account at any given time. If you have two 3DS units as I do, you have to transfer the license by linking/unlinking and transferring system settings. This can only be done once every 7 days. Overall it is a horrible nuisance and is the reason I avoid eShop games given the opportunity. Gameplay wise there is no difference, but license wise eShop games are a royal pain.

Comment: @andon-m-coleman there is always some device attachment on downloadable titles for consoles, but that really has no bearing here.

Comment: Well, your statement that they are identical is incorrect is all I am saying. If I have the card-based game, I can pop it out of my 3DS XL and into my 3DS when the battery dies. You cannot swap the SD card out and do the same with the eShop version :-\

Comment: Being in Europe, and therefore already having a physical copy, I can confirm they transfer just fine.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Again, a distinction irrelevant to the discussion.

Comment: Not irrelevant; you went off on a tangent when you claimed that there was no difference between retail and downloadable games.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman You are referring to the differences of the mediums, not the actual games themselves.